# How to clip layer output in MLP with `tf.keras.activations.relu()`?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, mlp, relu

According to the [documentation](https://keras.io/api/layers/activations/), `tf.keras.activations.relu(x, alpha=0.0, max_value=None, threshold=0)` seems to **clip** `x` within [threshold, max_value], but `x` must be specified. How can I use it for clipping the output of a layer in neural network? Or is there a more convenient way to do so?

Suppose I want to output the linear combination of all elements of a 10-by-10 2D-array only when the result is between 0 and 5.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

model = keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=[10, 10]))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='relu')    # output layer
```

Comment: Clipping the output of a layer in neural network ? Can you explain what do mean

Answer (score 0):

[Tensorflow clip_by_value link](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/clip_by_value)

For anyone who needs this in the future:

```
tf.clip_by_value(
    t, clip_value_min, clip_value_max, name=None
)
```